# preserve order of elements in PHP array foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array

```
$array = array(10 => "a", 11 => "b", 12 => "c");
```

and I want to loop in a foreach so that the order is preserved.

However, my foreach loop iterates the elements in the wrong order

```
foreach($array as $k => $v)
print($k." ".$v." /");
// 12 c / 11 b / 10 a /
```

what can I do about that?

Comment: this is weird, you can use one of the sort function http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: Your array assignment isn't valid syntax. Please show how you're actually defining the array.

Comment: he's saying that you are a lyer

Comment: This is **NOT** true. Check the example here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/WmXKqp

Comment: Tried it with multiple ways of array assigning and can't reproduce this error. Show us the real way you are defining your array. Example: http://codepad.org/cUqwBuWN

Comment: Solved: it was a problem in the display of the array (using firephp it showed me a different order than the actual order of the array).

Comment: If you solved it, you can post an answer to the question, and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using **asort**

```
$array =array(10 =>'a', 11=>'b', 12=>'c');
arsort($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." ".$value." /";
}
```

**Output**: `12 c /11 b /10 a /`

You can use **shuffle**

```
$array =array(10 =>'a', 11=>'b', 12=>'c');
shuffle($array);
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key." ".$value." /";
}
```

But this `not maintains the key association`

**Output**: `0 b /1 a /2 c /`